# ¿Cómo saber sobre que commit estoy trabajando?

Tags: git, git-commit

Estaba trabajando en un proyecto web, no sé lo que he hecho con Git, pero ahora mis archivos son de hace casi dos meses atrás. Me gustaría saber a que commit anterior he ido a parar.

Comment: el comando `git log -1`

Comment: `git log` te muestra el historial desde el commit actual hacia atrás.

Comment: @JackNavaRow: Perfecto! Por favor, edita una respuesta para que pueda validarla.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Para ver todos los commits en tu maquina puedes usar [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

```
git log
```

Si quieres ver los ultimos n commits (*donde "n" es la cantidad de commits que quieres ver*), suponiendo que quiero ver los ultimos 5:

```
 git log -5
```

Si solo quiero ver solo el ultimo basta con hacer `git log -1`

---

Si quieres ver el commit con solo los ultimos siete digitos(que es comun verlo asi) ejecuta el siguiente comando:

```
git log -1 --pretty=format:%h
```

Tambien es valido y mucho mejor :

```
git log -1 --abbrev-commit
```

tambien existe comando es el git [shortlog](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-shortlog)

```
git shortlog
```

Answer (score 2):

Obtener hash ids de los últimos commits, con el siguiente comando vamos a ver los últimos 10 ids:

```
?$ git log -10 --pretty="%H"
```